# Reloading Javascript on site after pressing an image (function)

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an mp3 player that selects random song from a list of variables. There is the code:

```
<b>Title</b>: <span id='songTitle'></span><br>
<b>Album</b>: <span id='songAlbum'></span><br>

<audio class="audio-element" controls="true" preload="none">

<!-- Adding audio sources -->

            <source src="mp3file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
<br>
<b>Your outdated browser does not support HTML5. <br>
Get Mozilla Firefox <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/new/"> >HERE< </a></b>

</audio>

<script>
var songs =
[
    { filename: "title1.mp3", title: "title1", album: "Album1" },
    { filename: "title2.mp3", title: "title2", album: "Album2" },
    // add more songs here...
];

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
var song = songs[randomIndex];
document.querySelector("source").src = song.filename;
document.getElementById("songTitle").textContent = song.title;
document.getElementById("songAlbum").textContent = song.album;
</script>
```

Is there an option, that after pressing a specifed image the code will refresh (it will again choose a song and show its specifics) without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: try using `jQuery` and then check the documentation of this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code you want to refresh in a function.

```
<script> 
var songs = ...
function f(){
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
    var song = songs[randomIndex]; document.querySelector("source").src = song.filename;
    document.getElementById("songTitle").textContent = song.title;
    document.getElementById("songAlbum").textContent = song.album;
}
</script>
```

Then set the function as a `callback` of onclick. As this:

```
<img ... onclick="f();" ... />
```

Comment: Nothing really happens, when clicking the image... Could you show me how to do it on JSfiddle?

Comment: @Ainei would you mind giving me the code of your `<img>`

Comment: Here it is: `<img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2256/hamburg/32/refresh.png" onclick="f();" />`

Comment: No, still nothing is happening :(

Comment: @Ainei what's your browser

Comment: @Ainei what if you use `<a onclick="alert('aaa')"><img ...(without onclick)></a>`

Comment: @Ainei try this `<img ... onclick="alert('hi')" ... >`

Comment: OK, now the title and images work perfectly fine when using the <a> tag (i made the function like you told me), but the mp3 player doesn't work at all (i guess the source doesn't change properly), my browser is Mozilla Firefox

Comment: EVERYTHING IS WORKING NOW, THANK YOU <3 I needed to use the `document.getElementById("mp3Player").load();` code in my function to reload the mp3, everything works like a charm now